# Why does this.One() call the overrider method from class B and not the virtual one from class A?

Tags: c#

```
class A
{
    public virtual int one()
    {
        return 100;
    }

    public virtual int two()
    {
        return 200;
    }

    public virtual int three()
    {
        return this.one();
    }
}

class B : A
{ 
    public override int one()
    {
        return 300;
    }

    public override int two()
    {
        return this.one();
    }

    public override int three()
    {
        return base.three();
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A b = new B();
        Console.WriteLine(b.three());
    }
}
```

Why does this code return "300"?

Comment: Because "This ... is ... Sparta!". Kidding aside, that is what a virtual method should do.

Answer (score 2):

Because it's `virtual`.

The whole point of `virtual` methods is that you always call the overridden version.

Answer (score 2):

That is the definition of an `override`.

The `virtual` keyword basically means, "Subclasses can override this method".

The `override` keyword basically means, "My base class has a virtual method that I am redefining"

I think your confusion is because the `this.one()` is called from the class `A`.  But, the `this` still refers to an instance of the class `B`, which is why the method on `B` is called.

Comment: well i know what virtual does, and i know that base.three would call the three method in class A, but why does this.three in class A call the method one in class B? shouldn't it call the one method in class A?

Comment: No.  `this` refers to a specific instance.  That instance has `one` overriden with `B`'s implementation.

Answer (score 0):

What @SLaks said.

But specifically, `b.three()` invokes `B.three`, which invokes `A.three`, which invokes `B.one`.

Comment: i get the part untill A.three invokes B.one, i thought it would invoke A.one :S

Comment: @Olle: Calling `this.blah` invokes `blah` based on the *dynamic* type of `this`.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you say return base.three(); in the overridden method you should acutaly be calling return this.three(); other wise you'll be accessing the base class which is A.

Comment: That is intentional.  Your suggestion would call itself and recurse endlessly.

Comment: wouldn't that trigger a stackoverflow?